# How to connect Raspberry Pi to home network using laptop's Ethernet port?

Tags: windows, networking

I have a Wi-Fi router connected wirelessly to my laptop. I want to connect a headless Raspberry Pi to this network but my Wi-Fi router does not have an Ethernet port. So I was wondering if its possible to connect my Pi to my laptop via an Ethernet cable and then connect it to the home network. Is it possible? How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Google "raspberry pi connect to internet through laptop"

Or look at this [How to share my internet connection on a (Windows) computer with a Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/how-to-share-my-internet-connection-windows-with-raspberry-pi)

Please check if the questions already out there **before** asking a question.

Comment: but my raspberry pi is headless. So when it was connected to the router, i wud type 192.168.1.123 in putty and the ssh connection would be established and everything worked fine. but when i connect th e raspberry pi to my laptop and type 192.168.1.123 in putty, it gives a message "connection timeout" so i typed ipconfig and found out that the ip address for raspbery pi was 192.168.1.103 So when i typed the address in putty, it gives an error message "connection refused" what do i do?

Comment: On a normal network, the router would assign ip addresses, so computers can connect to each other, using DHCP. In a network where two computers are directly connected, you will need to use a static ip address, because there's no router to automatically assign them one. Read this guide: https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/