# Raspberry pi internet through ethernet cable

Tags: internet

I am tried to connect raspberry pi through ethernet cable by using ssh. I used DHCP server to connect it. That is successful. I can view raspberry pi desktop in xming. But I can't browse Internet in raspberry pi browser. How to configure internet connection through ethernet cable? My computer has connected Internet in WiFi. How to share it through the Ethernet cable to raspberry pi? Computer OS is windows 7.

Comment: https://anwaarullah.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/sharing-wifi-internet-connection-with-raspberry-pi-through-lanethernet-headless-mode/
most possibly it will help

Comment: What OS is your computer running?

Comment: My computer os is windows 7

Comment: @iNdra - your question may be a duplicate of the questions that I posted in my answer. If you can edit _your_ question so that it differs from those already asked, by providing different information, or by addressing a particular issue that _isn't_ covered in those other questions, that would be good. Else, it may get considered a "duplicate" by the moderators. Or "off topic", as it isn't particularly Pi specific. Also, if you can edit your question to include the platform that you are using (i.e. Windows 7), rather than having it in the comments, that would also be good. Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: http://advanceprojectswithrpi.blogspot.in/  This will help you i did the same.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered a few times already:

- [How can I connect my Pi directly to my PC and share the internet
  connection?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11684/how-can-i-connect-my-pi-directly-to-my-pc-and-share-the-internet-connection)
- [How to share my internet connection (Windows) with Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/how-to-share-my-internet-connection-windows-with-raspberry-pi)