# Connecting to laptop wifi via ethernet

Tags: wifi, ethernet, ethernet-port, laptop

I have been trying to connect my pi to the internet for many hours now and to no avail. (I am on Windows 8.1) I have went through many tutorials, so far I have tried:

1. Turning my wifi internet connecting sharing
2. Adding the lines ip = 169.254.137.10 (aritrary ip for my pi) :: 169.254.137.1 (my computer's ip address) to \boot\cmdline.txt. It is interesting to note that once I do this and the above step, I am no longer able to SSH into the pi. I am able to use ifconfig to get my pi's ip address and it says the ethernet is connected but the internet just does not work. I can ping 8.8.8.8 although I am not sure exactly what that does.
3. Lastly, I tried bridging my wifi and ethernet connection.

Comment: How are you trying to connect?  Wired or wirelessly?  How does your PC connect to the internet?  Wired or wirelessly?  Why can't you connect the Pi to the same thing the PC is connected to?

Comment: Possible Duplicate.
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/how-to-share-my-internet-connection-windows-with-raspberry-pi/23631#23631