# problems connecting pi to Win10 laptop with connection sharing

Tags: raspbian, networking, windows

So I have a Pi3 (Jessie) with some of my own software on it, its at home now and happily connected to my wifi, but Im going to need to travel with it and show the software on the Pi to others.

I have VNC and SSH on my Win 10 laptop, and I have VNC and SSH enabled on the Pi.  I am running into trouble with networking, for my software to work it must be able to reach the internet and I want to plug the Pi into the laptop via Ethernet, and have the Pi reach the internet via the Laptop WiFi so when Im out and about I only need to manage WiFi access on the Laptop.

I have seen numerous guides to acheive this, but they just arent working.

Problem 1: Plugging the Pi into the laptop does not put the Pi on the same subnet as the laptop, Laptop is 192.168.137.1 255.255.255.0  and Pi is 169.254.72.93 255.255.0.0.
Tried setting a static ip in /etc/dhcpcd.conf and it kind of worked (I could SSH) but the Win10 Laptop didnt recognise the network.

Problem 2: Even with the static IP on the Pi, the laptop does not share its WiFi connection with the Pi.
I think the cause is that the Ethernet connection on the Laptop is marked as Public, I tried resetting it to Private, but it reverts (Im guessing becasue the Ethernet connection is unrecognised).

EDIT: As soon as the Pi is plugged into the Laptop via Ethernet, the Pi cannot resolve any hosts on the internet, unplug the Ethernet cable and the Pi connects to internet over WiFi without issues.

ICS is set on the Laptop

Comment: You have told us all the things which don't work, but **NOTHING** about what you did. Have you set ICS on the laptop?

Comment: Yes ICS is set, but it does not work, in the WiFi connection the ICS checkbox and the checkbox to allow other network users to control the connection, and in the dropdown Ethernet is selected

Comment: Try reading [http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/how-to-share-my-internet-connection-on-a-windows-computer-with-a-raspberry-pi#23631](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/how-to-share-my-internet-connection-on-a-windows-computer-with-a-raspberry-pi#23631). It might have an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure wheter it is resolved, but check this:
Obtaining an IP address from the 169.254.0.0 255.255.0.0 range means your DHCP client requests for an addres but it doesn't receive one. Hence it is giving itself a self assigned IP address form the 169.254.0.0 255.255.0.0 range. It looks like there is something wrong with your ICS settings (DHCP server, Firewall).